# Relationship between two classes (page object model) throws null pointer exception while passing objects

Tags: java, selenium, pom.xml, pageobjects

I am new to the forum. Sorry if the question is too lengthy. I have pasted four files. Two class files are the PageObject files. One file is the test file and the other is to initialize WebDriver.

I am getting a null pointer exception when I run the Login Test file.

//Firstpage

```
package com.base.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.Reporter;

public class ActitimeLoginPage {
protected WebDriver driver;

public ActitimeLoginPage(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

@FindBy(xpath="//input [@ name = 'username']")
public WebElement txtusername;

@FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='password']")
public WebElement txtpassword;

@FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='submit']")
public WebElement btnLogin;

@FindBy(xpath="//table[1]/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]")
public WebElement versionnumber;

@FindBy(xpath="//a[@href='http://www.actimind.com']")
public WebElement actimindlink;

public Opentaskpage login(String username, String password){
    txtusername.sendKeys(username);
    Reporter.log("Entered Username",true);
    txtpassword.sendKeys(password);
    Reporter.log("Entered password",true);
    btnLogin.click();
    Reporter.log("clicked on login",true);

    return new Opentaskpage(driver);

}

}
```

---

//Second page

```
package com.base.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.Reporter;

public class Opentaskpage {
protected WebDriver driver;

public Opentaskpage(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

@FindBy(xpath="//td[contains(text(),'Open Tasks')]")
public WebElement Heading;

@FindBy(xpath="/login.do?logout=1")
public WebElement btnLogout;

public void Logout(){
    btnLogout.click();
    Reporter.log("Clicked on logout",true);
    //return new ActitimeLoginPage(this.driver);
}


}
```

//Precondtion file

```
package com.base.generic;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class SuperTestNg {


public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
@BeforeMethod
public void precondtion(){

    driver.get("http://indbrnb0033/login.do");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();



}

@AfterMethod
public void postcondtion(){
    driver.close();

}

}
```

// Testfile

```
package com.Acti.Tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.base.generic.SuperTestNg;
import com.base.pages.ActitimeLoginPage;
import com.base.pages.Opentaskpage;

public class Login extends SuperTestNg {
@Test
public void Test_Login(){

    ActitimeLoginPage page = new ActitimeLoginPage(driver);
    Opentaskpage page2 = page.login("admin", "manager");
    page2.Logout();


}

}
```

I don't know how exactly to frame the question. A method of first page returns a constructor, and I am not able to initialize the second page.

Please help if I am doing something wrong, or show me the best way to follow. Thanks in advance.

I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.actitime.OpentaskPage.clicklogout(OpentaskPage.java:20)
    at com.actitime.ActitileLogin_Test.main(ActitileLogin_Test.java:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo. Can you change the input parameter's name to "driver" in following constructor:

```
public Opentaskpage(WebDriver drier){
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

}

It says "drier", change it to "driver" and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have edited the above lines of code and i am getting same error :-)